# $E$ and $B$ fields in Axial Gauge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, electromagnetism, gauge

I am trying to compute the $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields in the Axial gauge ($n \cdot \vec{A}=0$) where $n^2=1$, but I'm having trouble seeing the usefulness/how it simplifies the equations.

Comment: You may choose $\vec n$ as the unit direction $\vec e_z$, so that $A_\mu= (A_0,A_x, A_y, 0)$

Comment: Is there an easy way to compuse $\nabla \cdot \vec{A}$? I guess, I'm not sure what the first step is in computing $E$ or $B$ with this gauge is.